# What user is used to run a script launched by a udev rule?

Tags: shell-script, udev

When I write my own udev rules to call a shell script, who is the calling user or group?

Comment: The easiest way to answer this question is just to have your script run `id` and save the output somewhere.

Comment: @larsks could you maybe tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Run `id > /path/to/somefile`, then inspect `/path/to/somefile` after your script is triggered?

Comment: @larsks nothing happens after the udev rules calls the script. 
Only this line `uid=1000(unix) gid=1000(unix) groups=1000(unix),10(wheel) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023` has been written from the call `id > logfile.log`